# How to check that how many times the handler has been executed

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable

Here is my Method i want to check a that a circle lies on the button for five seconds for this i have used a runnable.but a problem is that i want to check it every second that the position of the circle changes or not if the circle position have been changes then start the handler timer from start for the new position otherwise call the method

```
private Runnable createRunnable(int paramPosition)
{
    Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            if (numOfSeconds == 5)
            {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                numOfSeconds = 0;
                if (paramPosition == circlePosition)
                {
                    methodCall(paramPosition);
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                } 
                else
                {
                    if (paramPosition == circlePosition)
                    {
                        numOfSeconds++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numOfSeconds = 0;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
            }
        }
      return aRunnable;
    };
}
```

so how i can perform this work please suggest a method to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: if you want to animate something use `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator`, not a `Handler`

Comment: I want to animate it but first want to determine that the circle is above the button for five seconds or not?